# Selecting most recent result when NULL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables with a fairly odd relationship with each other, and I'm trying to get some data out of them but not figuring out a good way to do it. The three tables are basically:

- A has a one-to-many relationship with B.
- B has a some-to-one relationship with C.

The "A" table has information about an overarching scope. For the sake of argument, let's say that table A contains a list of jobs that you've had or something like that. `A.Id` is the primary key for A.

The "B" table contains "spotlight" detalils about things relating to the "A" table. `B.Id` is the primary key for B, it has a `B.Timestamp` to indicate the time that the event happened, and it has a `B.AId` column to indicate which "A" it refers back to.

This is where things get complicated. The "C" table contains information about things relating to *some* entries in "B". It has two columns, essentially `C.Bid` and `C.Value`. If you were to `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON B.AId = A.ID LEFT JOIN C ON C.Bid = B.Id`, you'd be left with something like this:

```
A.Id    B.Id    C.Value  (... and other columns, of course...)
   1       1         12
   1       2       NULL
   1       3       NULL
   1       4         13
   1       5       NULL
   2       6         91
   2       7         12
   2       8       NULL
   2       9       NULL
   2      10       NULL
   3      11         92
   3      12         91
   3      13       NULL
   3      14         92
```

etc...

Now, I've got the timestamps in the "B" table that can help me get an understanding of when the `C.Value` changes,  but what if I wanted to see the expected value of `C.Value` when `B.Id` = 10? Based on the data in there, I *know* that the right answer is still `C.Value = 12` since it hasn't changed, but I have no good way of visualizing it.

So, what I'm asking for, basically, is help to construct a query that can show me `A.Id, B.Id` and the *most recent non-null* `C.Value` using `B.Timestamp` as the criteria. The Ids can come out of order at times, but the Timestamp is always correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Create an inline view joining B to C and return only the max(timeStamp) and AID value from B where C.Value is not null.  then join this back to your base set in table B.  This would then give you only A/B records which have a max timestamp where C value is not null.

Comment: Let's say I provided an answer; it would have some bits at the beginning, some bits in the middle, and an end bit. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @xQbert ... and then magic happens and suddenly I see the missing `C.Value` fields somehow? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't fully understand the question yet.  Sample data with an expected result would really help.  Especialyl where A has 3 B ID records and only the earliest or second earliest record is related to a value in C.

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.Value
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.ID = B.AID
INNER JOIN (SELECT AID, max(timestamp) mTimeStamp 
            FROM B 
            INNER JOIN C
              on B.ID = C.BID
            WHERE C.Value is not null
            GROUP BY AID) Z
 on B.AID = Z.AID 
 and B.TimeStamp = Z.mTimeStamp
LEFT JOIN C
 on C.BID = B.ID
```

So we return all values from A.ID, B.ID, C.value from a limited set.

By joining to inline view 'Z' we limit B records to those whose MAX(timestamp) for each AID value which has a non-null C value. Thereby eliminating all A.ID and B.ID's which don't have a C value; and who are not the max.

This assumes that if you have a situation where I have an A.ID with multiple B IDs say 1,2,3  and only 2 has a value.  then you want that record (2) not 3.

I suppose we could use an exists query to see if the BID in question exists in the C table with a value, but since you want the value returned a join made more sense to me.